# My coriander is drooping

Tags: cilantro

I am a newbie to caring for plants.

I have recently planted coriander seeds indoors with a grow light (as I do not get much sunlight). My coriander had been sprouting well for first 2 weeks. Now it is starting to droop. What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: Thank you,  Im using LED lights which I have kept about 9-10cm above the plant. I will move it closer or maybe try to find a sunny spot outdoors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't providing enough light to your seedlings - they should be about an inch/2.5cm tall at this stage in their development - instead, they're very leggy. If you're using fluorescent lights, they should be about 3in/7cm above the plants (raise the lights as the plants grow). LEDs should probably be about the same distace above the plant. With LEDs, you can choose different wavelengths of light, but at this stage, the wavelengths are less important than later on (when they start getting their true leaves). I hope that you are not using incandescent lights - in my opinion, it's extremely difficult to grow anything under them.

So - to help your seedlings, give them more light. The legginess will not get better, but new growth will be normal from this point on.